# read multiple paths from a .txt file in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

I have a batch script which requires to read multiple directory paths mentioned in config.txt. I am able to achieve this for one directory path but modified version of it is not working for multiple paths.

Below is the sample which is working fine.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do set "DataPath=%%L"
set "DataPath=%DataPath:/=\%"
echo Application path is: %DataPath%
```

How to modify this to handle for multiple directory paths.

**EDIT:**

Below is my attempt to get two paths and '%DataPath%' is printing the value.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=" %%L in (config.txt) do set 
"DataPath=%%L"&set "filepath=%%M"
 set "DataPath=%DataPath:/=\%"
 set "filepath=%filepath:/=\%"
 echo Application path is: %DataPath%
 echo Application path is: %filepath%
```

Comment: Your working code looks incorrect to me. Use either `"delims=" %%L in (config.txt)` or `"usebackq delims=" %%L in ("config.txt")`. I would recommend the latter. As far as your question is concerned, we're not here to write it for you, you need to write it and post here a [mcve] of it should it exhibit a specific issue.

Comment: To help you to do that, I would recommend that you place all of your commands within a parenthesised `do` section, and within that enable then use delayed expansion, ending it as necessary.

Comment: @Compo,  added the block which I tried for two directory paths. Also the same has been tried by adding paranthesis `do` block, but not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the advice I gave in the comments, which you didn't implement in your edit, the following methodology is what I was expecting you to come up with:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%L In ("config.txt") Do (
    Set "DataPath=%%L"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "DataPath=!DataPath:/=\!"
    Echo Application path is: !DataPath!
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

*This assumes that `config.txt` contains a list, one per line, of just file paths.*

Answer (score 0):

Array version of Path recovery from file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_P=0"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a IN (%userprofile%\desktop\logfile.txt) DO (
    Set /a _P+=1
    Set "Pathway[!_P!]=%%a"
)

::: use the below to take actions with elements in the array.
::: For example, search the array for specific files to delete/copy/move/open.

FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,!_P!) DO (
    ECHO Path !%%e! = !Pathway[%%e]!
)
pause
```